# Why isn't this JQuery code working on IE8 and IE9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

This function updates my content using the `.load` method from JQuery. The code works as intended on Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox, but does not work at all in IE8 nor IE9.

Here is its content:

```
 $(function(){

   var newHash='';
    $contentwrapper = $("#contentwrapper");

    $("nav").delegate(".menuOptions", "click", function() 
    {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function()
    {
        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);  
        $contentwrapper.load(newHash + " #contentcolumn");
        setTimeout(TitleUpdater, 200);
    });
 });

 function TitleUpdater()
 {
     top.document.title=$("#contentcolumn").attr("title");
 }
```

I would like to know how to make this code compatible with Internet Explorer! Thank you.

Edit:  On Firefox and Chrome, this code only replaces one big `<div id="contentcolumn">...</div>` and all the style around stays the same as it was before the script execution. While IE8 and IE9  just remove ALL my html code by `<div id="contentcolumn">...</div>` (it even writes over the `head` and `body` tags). This is really weird!

Here is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vladi Manaev</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bagums.css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="maincontainer">

            <div id="topsection">
                <div id="banner"></div>
                <div class="navbar">
                    <div class="navbar-inner">
                        <div class="container">
                            <nav> 
                                <a class="brand" href="">Bagums.com</a>
                                <ul class="nav">
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Basic Tutorials<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a class="menuOptions" href="BasicTutorials/CTutorial.html" name="CTutorial">C</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="menuOptions" href="BasicTutorials/CppTutorial.html" name="CppTutorial">C++</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="menuOptions" href="BasicTutorials/CsharpTutorial.html" name="CsharpTutorial">C#</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="menuOptions" href="BasicTutorials/JavaTutorial.html" name="JavaTutorial">Java</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="menuOptions" href="BasicTutorials/OtherTutorials.html" name="OtherTutorials">Others</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Projects<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a class="menuOptions" href="MyProjects/CProject.html">C</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="menuOptions" href="MyProjects/CppProject.html">C++</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="menuOptions" href="MyProjects/CsharpProject.html">C#</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="menuOptions" href="MyProjects/JavaProject.html">Java</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="menuOptions" href="MyProjects/Others.html">Others</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>

                                <ul class="nav pull-right">
                                    <li class="dropdown-toggle"><a class="menuOptions" href="OtherPages/Links.html">Links</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-toggle"><a class="menuOptions" href="OtherPages/Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-toggle"><a class="menuOptions" href="OtherPages/About.html">About</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        </div> <!-- container -->
                    </div> <!-- navbar-inner -->
                </div><!-- navbar -->
            </div><!-- topsection -->

            <div id="contentwrapper">
                <div id="contentcolumn" title="Vladi Manaev">
                    <div id="mainPostsTitle">Latest News</div>

                    <div class="postWrapper">
                        <div class="post">
                            <div class="postTitle"><div class="postTitleTxt">Third post on website</div></div>
                            <div class="postInfo"> Aug 4, 2012 @ 7:23 pm</div>
                            <div class="postContent">
                                <p>
                                    CONTENT
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="postWrapper">
                        <div class="post">
                            <div class="postTitle"><div class="postTitleTxt">Second post on website</div></div>
                            <div class="postInfo"> Aug 4, 2012 @ 7:22 pm</div>
                            <div class="postContent">
                                <p>
                                     CONTENT
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="postWrapper">
                        <div class="post">
                            <div class="postTitle"><div class="postTitleTxt">First post on website</div></div>
                            <div class="postInfo"> Aug 4, 2012 @ 6:48 pm</div>
                            <div class="postContent">
                                <p>
                                       CONTENT
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div><!-- contentcolumn -->
            </div><!-- contentwrapper -->

            <div id="footer"> 
                <nav>
                    <div> Copyright &copy; 2012 created by <a class="menuOptions" href="OtherPages/Contact.html"> Vladi Manaev</a></div>
                </nav>
            </div><!-- footer -->

        </div><!-- maincontainer -->

        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the page load faster -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>


    <script>
     $(function(){

       var newHash='';
        $contentwrapper = $("#contentwrapper");

        $("nav").delegate(".menuOptions", "click", function() 
        {
            window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
            return false;
        });

        $(window).bind('hashchange', function()
        {
            newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);  
            $contentwrapper.load(newHash + " #contentcolumn");
            setTimeout(TitleUpdater, 200);
        });
     });

     function TitleUpdater()
     {
         top.document.title=$("#contentcolumn").attr("title");
     }

</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is not working in IE, specifically

Comment: What errors? what's not working as you expect? what symptoms?

Comment: Have you debugged and looked at what is returned from the Ajax call, is it what you expect? Have you inspected the page to see what is added?

Comment: You may want to define your function `TitleUpdater` before it is referenced. You also may want to ensure your variables are defined in the proper scope (it looks like you intended to define `$contentwrapper` in the closure, but it is global (or in some undisclosed outer scope). Debugging these kinds of common mistakes may help reveal the problem.

Comment: Functions are [hoisted](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting) to the top of the parent in JavaScript, so this is a non-issue.

Comment: what is "nav"? Is that an Id?

Comment: @jcolebrand $("nav") finds tag <nav> in DOM.

Comment: and IE8 doesn't support non-standard tags, and I'm not sure I'm familiar with that tag.

Comment: This is not the issue, because `.load` is firing. The issue is that `load` is replacing the document body.

Comment: Probably not, however, my point being, he's got code that can't possibly work in IE8, so how are we to know what else he's done that won't work in IE8

Comment: @Vlad Do this, so Austin et al can shush, make us a bare-minimum jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem. Then we can tell you exactly what the issue is. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: So very true, but what you omit is that they will break older browsers when used for sizzle queries.

Comment: @Vlad what are in the javascript files (besides jQuery, we know about jQuery)

Comment: @jcolebrand in bagums.js there is only the code i posted above nothing else.

Comment: Here is your jsfiddle, without the CSS. If you provide that I can include that as well, as can anyone else here: http://jsfiddle.net/pAU2R/

Comment: I have added a URL on the post with tomcat running my webpage ... try to use it with IE and u will see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i changed my href to start with # like this:

```
<a class="menuOptions" href="#BasicTutorials/CTutorial.html" name="CTutorial">C</a>
```

...

It start working on IE as well!
My guess is that window.location.hash does not work on IE... and when i added "#" by hand it solved the problem.

Thanks everyone for trying to help !